# Are there any awards for children's science fiction literature?

Tags: childrens-novel, awards

I know there are many awards for science fiction works in general, such as the Hugo and Nebula. Are there any awards specifically for children's science fiction literature?

Answer (score 14):

[The Golden Duck](http://www.goldenduck.org/) awards "**are designed to encourage science fiction literature for children**" and have been presented yearly at [Worldcon](http://www.worldcon.org/) since 1992.

The categories include

> **Picture Book**:  Given for books written for very young children.
>
> **Eleanor Cameron Award for Middle Grades**: Given for books written for grades 2 to 6.
>
> **Hal Clement Award for Young Adult**: Given for books written for grades 6 to 12.
>
> **Special Awards**: Given to acknowledge a book, author, illustrator or publisher not fitting in one of the other catagories. This award is created on an as-needed basis.

More recently, the [Monica Hughes Award](http://www.bookcentre.ca/awards/monica_hughes_award_science_fiction_and_fantasy) has been honoring Sci-Fi books for adolescents, but only Canadian authors are eligible.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few children's SF awards. Most awards for kids' SF are either one in a system of awards or categories within larger awards. The Golden Duck awards are the only ones I can think of specializing in kids' SF, without being part of something bigger.

**General awards**

- SFWA presents the [Andre Norton Award](http://www.sfwa.org/tag/andre-norton-award/) for best [young adult book](http://www.sfadb.com/Andre_Norton_Award) at the Nebula award ceremony.
- *Locus Magazine* presents a [Locus Award](http://www.sfadb.com/Locus_Awards) for best [YA book](http://www.sfadb.com/Locus_Awards_Winners_By_Category#yabk).
- [Golden Duck Awards](http://www.goldenduck.org/) are given for [YA](http://www.sfadb.com/Golden_Duck_Awards_Winners_By_Category#hal), [middle grades](http://www.sfadb.com/Golden_Duck_Awards_Winners_By_Category#mid),  and [picture book](http://www.sfadb.com/Golden_Duck_Awards_Winners_By_Category#pic).

**Genre awards**

- The Horror Writers' Association gives a [Bram Stoker Award](http://www.horror.org/stokers.htm) for superior achievement in [work for younger readers](http://www.sfadb.com/Bram_Stoker_Awards_Winners_By_Category#young).
- The [Mythopoeic Society](http://www.sfadb.com/Mythopoeic_Awards_Winners_By_Category#childf) presents the [Mythopoeic Fantasy Award for Children’s Literature](http://www.sfadb.com/Mythopoeic_Awards_Winners_By_Category#childf).

**Regional awards**

- Australia's [Aurealis Awards](http://www.aurealisawards.com/) have four kids' categories: [YA novel](http://www.sfadb.com/Aurealis_Awards_Winners_By_Category#yn), [YA short story](http://www.sfadb.com/Aurealis_Awards_Winners_By_Category#ys), [children's long fiction/novel](http://www.sfadb.com/Aurealis_Awards_Winners_By_Category#null), and [children's short fiction](http://www.sfadb.com/Aurealis_Awards_Winners_By_Category#null).
- Canada's [Sunburst Award](http://www.sunburstaward.org/) gives a [YA award](http://www.sfadb.com/Sunburst_Award).
- The [Canadian Children’s Book Centre](http://www.bookcentre.ca/award) gives several awards for children's lit, including the [Monica Hughes Award for Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://www.bookcentre.ca/awards/monica_hughes_award_science_fiction_and_fantasy).
- The Israeli Society for Science Fiction and Fantasy gave a [Geffen Award](http://english.sf-f.org.il/act_gefenaward.htm) for best [YA or children's book](http://www.sfadb.com/Geffen_Awards_Winners_By_Category#null), once.
- New Zealand's [Sir Julius Vogel Awards](http://www.sffanz.org.nz/sjv/sjvAwards.shtml) include one for best [YA novel](http://www.sfadb.com/Sir_Julius_Vogel_Awards_Winners_By_Category#null).

And I'm sure there are some I missed, especially for other languages.